# Fastest way to get interval from sorted list?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, arraylist

Let's say there's the `Element` class with `position` property.

```
public class Element {

   private float position;

   public float getPosition() {
      return position;
   }

   public void setPosition(float position) {
      this.position = position;
   }
}
```

Also, there's the `ArrayList<Element> elements` holding elements with randomly assigned `position` values. Elements are then sorted ascending by position values.

Question: What is the fastest way of getting all elements within some position interval `<a,b>`, other then simply iterating through elements, like this:

```
for (Element element : elements) {
   if (element.getPosition() > a && element.getPosition() < b) {
      // Do something with an element.
   }
}
```

I assume there is a faster way, due to the assumption that the list is sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the start and the end of the range, and then iterate between them.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that there is an `Arrays.binarySearch` method.

Comment: @BoristheSpider question is about `List` so `Collections.binarySearch` would be probably more acuarte :)

Comment: But how to perform binary search if there are no elements corresponding to the bound of the interval? i.e. if Collections.binarySearch(elements, a) or Collections.binarySearch(elements, b)  returns null

Comment: @krsi: It does not return `null`. It returns the (modified) insertion index. Have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If all elements are unique (or you don't need to store duplicate elements), you can use a TreeSet which implements the NavigableSet interface:

```
TreeSet<Element> set = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Element> () {
    public int compare(Element e1, Element e2) {
        return Float.compare(e1.getPosition(), e2.getPosition());
    }
});

Set<Element> betweenAandB = set.subSet(a, false, b, false);
```

Comment: This method returns `from inclusive` to `to exclusive` - is seems that the OP wants both exclusive so the [other method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet(E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean)) would need to be used.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Indeed - amended.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it faster using two binary searches:

```
final int start = Collections.binarySearch(elements, a);
final int end = Collections.binarySearch(elements, b);
return elements.subList(start, end + 1);
```

Make sure your `Element` correctly implements `Comparable` interface:

```
public class Element implements Comparable {
    @Override
    public int compare(Element e1, Element e2) {
        return Float.compare(e1.getPosition(), e2.getPosition());
    }
}
```